# How to set tooltip at runtime in MFC Treeview?

Tags: c++, mfc

How to set tooltip at runtime in MFC Treeview ?

I am creating treeview like this :

```
                        m_pTreeview->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP |                     
            TVS_SINGLEEXPAND,CRect(38, 82, 220 ,250), this, IDC_NDS_TREEVIEW);
```

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some code : -- In .H file

```
afx_msg void OnMyTreeGetInfoTip(NMHDR pNMHDR, LRESULT pResult);
```

In BEGIN MESSAGE MAP block add -

```
ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT (TVN_GETINFOTIP, OnMyTreeGetInfoTip)
```

And use  handler

```
void CMyTreeView::OnMyTreeGetInfoTip(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMTVGETINFOTIP pGetInfoTip = (LPNMTVGETINFOTIP)pNMHDR;   
    CString strItemTxt = m_TreeCtrl.GetItemText(pGetInfoTip->hItem);
    strcpy(pGetInfoTip->pszText, strItemTxt);  
    *pResult = 0;   
}
```

Comment: You should edit your previous response instead of posting multiple ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the tooltips for items in the tree control, you need to add `TVS_INFOTIP` to the window styles in `Create` (see [list of tree-view styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760013%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)). You'll also have to handle the [`TVN_GETINFOTIP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773522%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) notification message to provide the tooltip text depending on the item.

Comment: can u provide me some sample on this ?

Comment: I have just added TVS_INFOTIP in treeview while creating but it is not showing any tooltip. how to do the next step ?

Answer (score 0):

Use TVS_INFOTIP style to tree-view, and handle the TVN_GETINFOTIP notification using an ON_NOTIFY handler. Typecast the NMHDR ptr to NMTVGETINFOTOOLTIP ptr as
(NMTVGETINFOTOOLTIP *)pnmhdr  and then set the tooltip string in this structure.

Answer (score 0):

Pankaj's answer works if you are deriving your own control from CTreeControl.
Cassablanca's answer is correct only the code is missing.

So here are some tips from my own experience.

- If you are not creating the control explicitly the GETINFOTIP style can be specified in the resource file where the control is being defined.
- otherwise the style can be modified at runtime by getting the tree's window handle

  HWND htreectrl = m_TreeCtrl.GetSafeHwnd();
  LONG nOldStyle = GetWindowLong(  htreectrl,  GWL_STYLE);
  LONG nNewStyle = nOldStyle & TVS_INFOTIP;
  SetWindowLong( htreectrl, GWL_STYLE, nNewStyle);
- To be able to handle GETINFOTIP:

  If you are using the TreeControl as a member control inside a dialog:

  ON_NOTIFY (TVN_GETINFOTIP, IDC_TREE, OnMyTreeGetInfoTip)

  Else if you are deriving your own control from CTreeControl then use this:

  ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(TVN_GETINFOTIP, OnMyTreeGetInfoTip)

Hope this helps someone.